# Is there a way to use aggregate functions real-time in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a custom query to pull data from MySQL database to Tableau.

'finalPayment' currently calculates final payment based on whether payment is split into deposit+invoice or full.

```
SELECT 
        *,
        CASE
            WHEN invoiceAmount IS NOT NULL THEN ((invoiceAmount + depositAmount)/100)
            ELSE (fullAmount/100)
            END AS final_payment
    FROM
        production
    WHERE 
        fullPaid = 1
        AND
        id IN
            (
            SELECT MIN(id)
            FROM production
            GROUP BY fullPaymentIntentID
            )
```

The issue now is that for customers that purchase n number of products, the fullAmount is logged for every entry. i.e. If a customer purchases 2 products of $100, there are two entries with $200. The logic has been fixed moving forwards, but for analysis of legacy data, I need to divide the fullAmount by the COUNT of 'fullPaymentIntentID'. I am currently using a shortcut by parsing the first entry of 'fullPaymentIntentID' using GROUP BY MIN. Is there a way for real-time evaluation of COUNT in a CASE statement?

```
CASE
    WHEN invoiceAmount IS NOT NULL THEN ((invoiceAmount + depositAmount)/100
    WHEN COUNT(fullPaymentIntentID) > 1 THEN (fullAmount/100/COUNT(fullPaymentIntentID))
    ELSE (fullAmount/100)
    END AS final_payment
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results are almost always helpful for clarifying questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem. It would be helpful to see the data model and some example data. Try this query and let me know if it was what you need.

```
SELECT 
        *,
        CASE
            WHEN invoiceAmount IS NOT NULL THEN ((invoiceAmount + depositAmount) / 100)
            ELSE (fullAmount / 100 / p1.quantity)
            END AS final_payment

    FROM production p
    
    INNER JOIN (SELECT fullPaymentIntentID, count(*) AS quantity FROM production GROUP BY fullPaymentIntentID) AS p1 ON p.fullPaymentIntentID = p1.fullPaymentIntentID
    
    WHERE fullPaid = 1;
```